# Sharing Files Without SMB 1.0

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, lan, smb

I just disabled the SMB 1.0 / CIFS support on W10 and now I cannot access shares on my LAN.
If I disabled SMBv1, should v2 and v3 still work?
Also, is there any other way (without external software) to share files on W10 on LAN?

Thanks in advance for helping me out ;) .

ANSWER: The app that I use on my Android device to access shares still uses SMBv1, that's the root cause.

Comment: What software are the other file servers using? Yes, you absolutely should be able to access their shares... unless they're running old SMB servers (XP or before, or old versions of SAMBA, etc.). Are you using Homegroups (introduced in Win7)? If so, you should still be able to see all computers there. Even if not, you should be able to connect to other machines by the usual `\\server\share\path\to\file\or\folder` syntax...

Comment: "If I disabled SMBv1, should v2 and v3 still work?" - Yes; If it doesn't it means your share doesn't support SMBv2 and SMBv3.  You do realize that, if you patch Windows 10, then it isn't vulnerable to the SMBv1 vulnerability.

Comment: some products still [require SMB1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2017/06/01/smb1-product-clearinghouse/) maybe you use one which only supports SMB1

Comment: @magicandre1981 You're right, SMB1 is still in the use in the app.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an android app that now supports SMB2/3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some products that require SMB1. Maybe you use one which only supports SMB1, so [check a list that Microsoft provides](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2017/06/01/smb1-product-clearinghouse/).

You should call the support of the product and request an Update so that the product uses SMB2/3 in the future.

If you use an Android, [look at this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.google.android.sambadocumentsprovider/), which now [supports SMB2 and 3](https://github.com/google/samba-documents-provider/commit/f667f46dce883ed7e2fc87a88c8b7087e956d8c7).

Comment: The "this app" link is 404. Please, update it.

Answer (score 0):

To check that you didn't disable SMBv2, run the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2Protocol
```

It just reads the state and should show TRUE